# Why cant i combine jquery css with jquery events?

Tags: jquery, css

i tried to make a sidebar permanently hidden until a .click eventhandler with the fade-in event until the event will be triggered, and the text of this bar should slid-down (speed of 500). Unfortunatly i tried and tried and googled lot of these functions/eventhandler? but couldnt figure it out how to make this work as wished.
and the id #about is the side bar, the id #about_me is an list item that should trigger the event, the id#about_profile is the content of the sidebar.
now back to main content, here is the code:

```
//second js code .css('visibility','hidden')
$('#about').css('visibility','hidden')
$("#about_me").click(function(){
    $("#about").fadeIn(500);
    $('#about_profile').slideDown(200)({

        });
    });
```

my second question is, why isnt this event not taking place? following code:

```
    $('#about').css('visibility','hidden',function(){
    $("#about_me").click(function(){
        $("#about").fadeIn(500);
        $('#about_profile').slideDown(200)({
    });
});
```

thank you for help
kind regards

ps: i ve searched even stackoverflows AQL(Asked-question Library)

Comment: You can't pass a function to `.css()` like that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5xYsV/3/ here is my full code ... i just gotten started with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery `.css` method doesn't accept a callback, and it is synchronous, meaning it doesn't actually need a callback parameter. Your first snippet is the correct way to do this.

```
$('#about').css('visibility','hidden');
$("#about_me").click(function(){
    $("#about").fadeIn(500);
    $('#about_profile').slideDown(200);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean with snippet? (sry english isnt my mother language)

Comment: The first piece of code in your question. I'll add it to my answer

Comment: There were a few syntax problems in your first piece of code, i corrected them in my answer.

Comment: ive did... an still nothing occures.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#about').css('visibility','hidden');

$("#about_me").click(function(){
     $("#about").fadeIn(500);
     $('#about_profile').slideDown(200);
});
```

That should do it.

Comment: i added the ; to the first line but still nothing happens.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/5xYsV/3 here is my full code ... i just gotten started with it

Comment: i dont get it ... i tried .hide() and when i refreshed the page the element showed it self and disapeard... i dont understand what the failure i did there. however your version of the script doesnt seem to have the same problem as mine thanks.

Comment: Just apply display: none; to the box in CSS, that way it won't show on page load, as javascript only runs once the page has got to it (unless you do something like document ready or window load etc).

Comment: ohh i see ... ive made lots of mistakes ..thanks. after .slideDown ive added some round and curly brackets... ok thanks alot ... now i relize that jquery is a piece of hard work and patience.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#about').hide();` instead of `$('#about').css('visibility','hidden');`

Comment: `.hide()` = `display:none` which basically doesn't consume any space.. but `visibility:hidden` consumes the space it has.. just that it will not be seen ;)

Comment: as vega says .. i tried the .hide event but when i reload the page one can see how the element gets hidden... and i am trying to make it hidden permanently till the event has been triggered.

Comment: Right, but `show` doesn't make visible something that's been `hidden`. [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/8A8XV/1/)

Comment: If [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) is a concern, hide the element in the HTML (faster) or with CSS (better practice) using `display: none;`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that fadeIn set the display property to block and does not alter the visibility property... You may be better off using css('display', 'none') or better .hide() as someone already suggested. Docs are here: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ and in the comments the "display: none" problem is mentioned.